# SSL Certificate Errors When Connecting to Heroku Postgres from Google Data Studio

Tags: postgresql, ssl, heroku, heroku-postgres

I'm using a Heroku Postgres instance on the hobby dev tier with Google Data Studio. I'm able to generate an SSL certificate and connect from Google Data Studio but every month or two I'm seeing the following error.

`Switchboard API call failed with error JDBC_HOST_NOT_REACHABLE: Unable to connect to Host: SSL error: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`

[screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rj2CC.png)

I'm following the instructions on this page to generate the SSL certificates:
https://plata.news/blog/integrate-google-data-studio-with-postgres-using-ssl/

Am I generating the SSL certificates correctly? Is this expected behavior for a Heroku Postgres instance on the hobby dev tier?

Comment: did manage to solve the issue?

Comment: @Amitk Unfortunately I did not. I ended up setting up a Postgres server in an instance hosted by GCP instead of using Heroku to avoid the issue